# Cakephp + HttpSocket component + Restful API

Tags: php, cakephp

Recently I am coding a small web page with CakePHP. The most of my models represent data that has to be collected through an external API with the `HttpSocket` component which provides `CakePHP 2.x`.

This is the main reason I include the following method in `AppModel.php`

```
public function get ($url, $options = array()) {
    $options += $this->default;
    $url .= 'api_key=' . $options['api_key'];
    $hs = new HttpSocket();

    return $hs->get($url);
}
```

I want to implement some measures to control the number of times CakePHP call the API, because it has limitations (100 request per minute and 1000 per hour, for example)

What is the best way to accomplish this?
I thought about store data related to the request in a new table but I am not sure if I can do queries from `AppModel.php`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new table like `api_call_log` and increment the count. You can simply get a model instance in your AppModel:

```
$ApiCallLog = ClassRegistry::init('ApiCallLog')
$ApiCallLog->log();
```

Put your logic for the count into the model method and pass arguments as you need, not sure what else you might need.

Instead of putting it in AppModel a behavior might be a better place and you can implement additional methods there as well as your code grows and attach it only to models that need it.

An alternative that is very likely less resource hungry than using a SQL DB is to use a Redis cache. So use Cache::read() and Cache::write() to get the actual count and increment it. This is very likely the better alternative if you get A LOT requests to the API. You might get collisions using a SQL DB if you don't lock the tables during the counting and incrementing operation. I never had this case but I would not count on that it won't happen.

Additional note: `get()` is a *very* generic name, I would rename it to `httpGet()`. Names that are not specific can be pretty confusing, especially if there are methods of the same name in other classes around.

Comment: I will try both options (DB and Cache) in the following days.
The `get` method name does not depends on me, is part of a component of CakePHP. 
Thanks for your answer mate.